# Alert notification if there is no update in 4 hours

Tags: workflow, time-dependent-workflow

I have a requirement where I have to send alert notification for a case if it is not updated for more than 4 hours (when the case is not closed). What will be the simplest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Escalation Rules](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=creating_escalation_rules.htm) for this purpose. It will send an email to a user and also optionally assign the case to another user (such as a manager). Unlike a workflow rule, it shows a red arrow that indicates the case has been escalated and needs attention.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use the declarative solution in Salesforce and the easiest option is to use [time-dependent triggers](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workflow_time_action_considerations.htm&language=en_US) . You would set the trigger to trigger after 4 hours and to evaluate, with a formula if the case is not closed.

You might also find [this](http://blog.shivanathd.com/2012/12/TimeTriggerWorkflow.html) helpful.